# Trick LaTeX into displaying different page numbers

Tags: page-numbering

Is it possible to 'trick' LaTeX into displaying different page numbers?

For a whole host of complicated reasons I would like to display

1 instead of 7

2 instead of 8

3 instead of 9

etc....

without changing the page counter. Is this needlessly tricky?

Comment: Difficult to say without some more details; how should the pages before page 7 (to be displayed as 1) be numbered?

Comment: Those numbers will be suppressed so wont be displayed.

Comment: Modifying `\thepage` is allowed, but not the counter?

Comment: If that's possible?

Comment: Maybe create a new counter `page` and use it in the page style?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This version (modified from egreg) would work with hyperref

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{Roman}
\pagestyle{empty}

This page has no number\newpage %1

This page has no number\newpage %2

This page has no number\newpage %3

This page has no number\newpage %4

This page has no number\newpage %5

This page has no number %6

\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\pagestyle{headings}

This is page 1\newpage

This is page 2

\end{document}
```

The problem when using `\pagenumbering{gobble}` with hyperref is that you get warnings because several pages have the same identifier and the pdf-page numbering is broken. If you have no problem with the empty pages being numbered with roman numerals in the pdf-pagecount but not in the print area of the file, then this should work.

Comment: This adds other problems if the page style shouldn't be empty.

Comment: @egreg That is certainly true. It only solves the problem assuming that Juggler added all necessary information.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need `hyperref`, the trick is very easy:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{gobble}

This page has no number\newpage %1

This page has no number\newpage %2

This page has no number\newpage %3

This page has no number\newpage %4

This page has no number\newpage %5

This page has no number %6

\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

This is page 1\newpage

This is page 2

\end{document}
```

Comment: I am using hyperref is that an issue?

Comment: @Juggler Yes, of course it is. Please, add details to your question.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this works

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\pageoffset{6}  %(7 - 1 = 6)

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\let\origthepage\thepage
\renewcommand{\thepage}{%
\ifnumgreater{\value{page}}{1}{\number\numexpr\value{page}+\numexpr\pageoffset-1}{\origthepage}
}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\clearpage

\pagestyle{plain}

\section{First}
\blindtext[30]
\section{Other}
\end{document}
```

I omitted a screenshot, it shows the feature (for a small document, untested for a larger one). `hyperref` works in here

**Edit** A better version, taking care of the current page value:

```
\documentclass{book}


\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\def\pageoffset{6}%
\newcounter{pagereset}
\let\latexthepage\thepage

\newcommand{\SwitchPagenumbering}{%
  \setcounter{pagereset}{\number\value{page}}%
  \renewcommand{\thepage}{%
    \ifnumgreater{\value{page}}{\value{pagereset}-1}{\number\numexpr\value{page}+\number\numexpr\pageoffset}{\latexthepage}%
  }%
}


\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\SwitchPagenumbering


\chapter{First}
\section{First}

\blindtext[30]
\typeout{Pagereset is \thepagereset: Page is \number\value{page}}

\section{Other}
\blindtext[20]
\section{Other}
\section{Other}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I have not much time right now to provide a better version, so be patient ...

Comment: I think, the page number before this *resetting* occurs, should be stored, to make the whole stuff more fail safe